# Using BIRT 3.2.17, set a number as persisent global variable, the toString() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, birt

Using BIRT 3.2.17, set a number as a persisent global variable on beforeFactory() reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable ("globalvar","1");

while trying to retrieve at  onPageStart() using

```
var cal = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable ("globalvar");
var incr=  parseInt(cal)+1;
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable ("globalvar", incr.toString());
```

the to.String() doesnt seem to be working, I am not able to set **incr** value to **globalvar.**

Comment: What do you mean that it is not working? what is the value of incr and globalvar in your case?

Comment: When i do reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable ("globalvar"), I get backthe value as null